# Why Puppeteer is not waiting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

My understanding is that in `await Promise.all(...)` the code should run as follows:

1. print first console.log
2. wait for 9 seconds
3. print last console.log

How can I make the 3rd print statement to be printed after 9 seconds rather than immediately?

**What actually happens**

All statements inside  `await Promise.all(...)` are executed simultaneously rather than serially.

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false, slowMo:100});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://google.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});


await Promise.all(

  [
    console.log('printing before waiting 9 sec'),
    page.waitFor(9000),
    console.log('printing after waiting 9 sec')
  ]

);


//await browser.close();
})().catch((error) =>{
  console.error("the message is " + error.message);
});


app.listen(3000, function (){
    console.log('server started');
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, functions in [Promise.all(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) are run concurrently. The purpose of this is to make sure **all of them are resolved** before your code continues. Return values are given in specified order, but the functions themselves fire all at once.

To run asynchronous functions in order, use [.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) or [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Since your only async function is `page.waitFor` (`console.log` is synchronous function), you can simply do this:

```
console.log('printing before waiting 9 sec')
await page.waitFor(9000)
console.log('printing after waiting 9 sec')
```

Comment: So this means that I would have to create new promises with ```New Promise``` constructor for each console.log() and thereafter call ```then``` on them? It would be really helpful if you could show me how you would solve the problem for my specific case scenario given that I am already running this code in an ```async``` function. Many thanks

Comment: @bibscy, simply use the code from my example instead of your `await Promise.all` block :-)